# question about the probability assignment that specifies the probability of semi-infinite intervals.

Tags: probability

A single part of my probability assignment is that

Q. Consider an experiment for which the sample space is the real line. A probability law assigns probabilities to subsets of the form (-∞, r].

- Find an expression for P[(r,s]] in terms of P[(-∞,r]] and P[(-∞,s]]. (r < s)

I solved that question, 
P[(-∞,s]] = P[(-∞,r]] + P[(r,s]]

 So, P[(r,s]] = P[(-∞,s]] - P[(-∞,r]].

And my real stuck is here.

- Find an expression for P[(s,∞)].

I tried to divide this probability into many sections but I can't get any clue from this problem.

Is there any appropriate expression for P[(s,∞)]?

Comment: Consider what $P[(-\infty,s]] + P[(s,\infty)]$ might mean

Comment: Um... 1 = P[(−∞,s]]+P[(s,∞)] , and 1 - ( P[(-∞,r]] + P[(r,s]] ) = P[(s,∞)]... Am i right?

Comment: Your statements are correct, but I suspect you do not need the second.  Just manipulate the first to get an expression for $P[(s,\infty)]$ in terms of $P[(-\infty,s]]$

Comment: I see, I sincerely appreciate that :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, $P[(-\infty,s]]+P[(s,\infty)]=1$ yields $P[(s,\infty)]=1-P[(-\infty,s]]$.